# Symmetric Frobenius structure.

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, monoidal-categories

I am new to the Frobenius Algebra course. One of my textbook exercises ask to prove:

Show that every finite-dimensional simple algebra admits a symmetric
Frobenius structure.

I have no idea how to proceed. Any reference or explicit proof will be a great help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [Wiki page on Frobenius algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_algebra) states:

> Any matrix algebra defined over a field k is a Frobenius algebra with Frobenius form $σ(a,b)=\mathrm{tr}(a·b)$ where $\mathrm{tr}$ denotes the trace.

A finite dimensional simple algebra is, of course, isomorphic to a matrix ring over a division ring extension of the field.

Actually the division ring part throws a wrench in this, because the form is not necessarily symmetric. However, quite often you are using algebraically closed $k$, whence this would not be an issue (the matrix ring would have to be over $k$ itself.)

(Added: in the comments, Andrew Hubery has mentioned that scalar extension can be used to navigate around the issue if the field is not algebraically closed. I'll add as necessary to explain.)

I believe there is also another approach where you can use a different characterization and select a linear functional whose kernel contains no nonzero left ideal, but I thought it depended on $k$ being infinite.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I could not see, why a finite-dimensional simple algebra is a matrix algebra, can you provide some reference? Moreover what about the symmetric condition?

Comment: @BhawanaDey A finite dimensional algebra is necessarily artinian, and a simple Artinian ring is a matrix ring like that by the Artinian wedderburn theorem.

Comment: @BhawanaDey what about the symmetric condition?  Tr(ab)=Tr(ba) is straightforward right?

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot for your comments!

Comment: A fin. dim. simple $k$-algebra is a matrix ring over a fin. dim. division algebra, so not necessarily a matrix ring over $k$.

Comment: The usual approach is therefore first to tensor with a splitting field extension. This gets you a full matrix ring, but over a finite field extension of $k$, and now you can take the trace.

Comment: @AndrewHubery Usually one uses "full matrix ring" to mean the entire set of matrices, and "matrix ring" for a representation of another algebra (which can be a subring). The thing that went wrong here when I edited was that I forgot the suggested form might not be acceptable when applied to a subring.

Comment: @AndrewHubery Taking the extension of scalars approach seems like a good idea, except I have no idea how to explain why the resulting form for the extension applies to the original algebra.  Is the idea simply to use the trace-form restricted to the original algebra as a subset?  It doesn't seem immediately  obvious why the form satisfies the right-ideal-avoidance condition.  But I wouldn't be surprised if extension of scalars cooperated.

Comment: That’s correct. If it vanishes on some ideal of the original algebra, then by linearity it vanishes on the extended ideal, so the extended ideal is zero. By flatness, the original ideal must be zero.

Comment: @AndrewHubery This may be the first example of reasoning with extensions and flatness that finally sticks with me.   Thanks for explaining!